# OptaPlanner: Drools rule on consecutive shift assignments

Tags: drools, optaplanner

The context is Employee Shift Assignment with OptaPlanner using Drools rules for calculating scores.
My Employees cannot work for, say, for more than three consecutive days without a rest day.
I implement such a constraint very stupidly as:

```
rule "No more than three consecutive working days"
    when
        ShiftAssignment(
            $id1 : id,
            $empoloyee : empoloyee != null,
            $shift1 : shift
            )
        ShiftAssignment(
            id > $id1,
            empoloyee == $empoloyee,
            shift.isConsecutiveDay($shift1),
            $id2 : id,
            $shift2 : shift
            )
        ShiftAssignment(
            id > $id2,
            empoloyee == $empoloyee,
            shift.isConsecutiveDay($shift2),
            $id3 : id,
            $shift3 : shift
            )
        ShiftAssignment(
            id > $id3,
            empoloyee == $empoloyee,
            shift.isConsecutiveDay($shift10)
            )
    then
        scoreHolder.penalize(kcontext);
end
```

I hope the name of the methods/variables clearly reveal what they do/mean.
Is there a more convenient and smart way to implement such a rule? Keep in mind that the three days above may need to change to a bigger number (I used three to avoid a more realistic ten and more lines of code in the rule). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume an employee takes up to a single shift per day and the `shift.isConsecutiveDay()` may be replaced by something like `shift.day == $shift1.day + 1`, `exists` can be used:

```
when
    ShiftAssignment($employee : empoloyee != null, $shift1 : shift)
    exists ShiftAssignment(employee == $employee, shift.day == $shift1.day + 1)
    exists ShiftAssignment(employee == $employee, shift.day == $shift1.day + 2)
    exists ShiftAssignment(employee == $employee, shift.day == $shift1.day + 3)
then
```

If such an assumption cannot be made, your solution should work, with one potential corner case to think about:

The rule tries to filter out combinations of the same shifts by the condition `id > $id1`. This condition works, but the IDs must be generated ascendingly by the time of the shift, otherwise, it clashes with `shift.isConsecutiveDay(...)`. In case this property cannot be guaranteed, checking for ID inequality could be preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I was hoping in a different solution: imagine now that you want somehow to "scale" the number of consecutive days from three to ten: with both your rule and mine _you need to add new lines_. That's precisely what I would like to avoid (if possible).

Comment: The ID is actually a `Long` generated from a `static` property of the class: when shifts are created (in chronological order) new IDs are generating (in ascending order).

Comment: I understand the concern about increasing the consecutive days in the rule. One way it might be resolved is by using the [Drools accumulate](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-rules-con_drl-rules), potentially with a custom accumulate function implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of rules to achieve this. First rule sets up the start of a consecutive work sequence, second one sets up the end, 3rd rule creates a "Work Sequence" to fit between the start and end. Finally the "Max Consecutive Days" rule actually checks your "Work Sequence" against a limit on number of consecutive days.

This paradigm is actually in the nurse rostering example:
https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/solver/nurseRosteringConstraints.drl